# Process and Executable Filenames

Tags: c#, process, executable

The C# Process class allows you to run a command-line executable in Windows. The Process.StartInfo class holds information about the command line job you want to run, including its path and filename.

My problem is that Process.Start() will throw an exception if the file does not exist. To try and avoid the exception, I coded a check to see if the file existed, but this did not work properly in all instances because a name might not exist as a file with that exact name, but might have an executable counterpart. For example, "C:\SoAndSo" might not exist as a file, but "C:\SoAndSo*.exe*" does, and *would have been found successfully when starting the Process command*.

I have hacked my checks to try the name given to me, and the name + ".exe" and ".bat", but this feels cludgy, and perhaps I am missing other executable extensions.

So: is there a command to ask the question: 'Do you have an executable version of the filename starting 'SoAndSo'?

Comment: If you are using a GUI, you can have a default filter of .bat and .exe, and allow them to select `All Files (*.*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id had a similar requirment.. & i solved it using the environment variable `%PATHEXT%`.

reference can be found [here](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm), 
say I'm trying to find a program called abcd then the app would look for

`*abc*.` with all extension combo available ion the `%PATHEXT%` variable..

I'd say this is a crude implementation.. but it worked for me.. I;m quite sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Although it was a close run thing for pragmatism of Jesus Ramos as compared to your answer, Anantha, I accepted this answer as being slightly closer to my intended / expected result; that being to avoid the exception and instead understand what extensions the system would consider executable. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not try to start the Process and wrap that in a try/catch and when you get a FileNotFoundException then you can simply print the output of that and exit? I see you want to try and avoid the exception but you might have more overhead trying to prevent it than just incurring it.

Comment: yes indeed I am trying to avoid relying on the exception. I take your point that there is a balance to this... I've not given up the hope that it might be possible to do something neater, however!

Comment: I believe this to be the neatest way to do it. Incurring an exception is not all that expensive I'm pretty sure it's more expensive to check the files in a directory for matches and such.

Comment: On balance I do agree that your approach is _pragmatic_, and _probably_ has less overhead... the spirit of the question was about testing and avoiding the exception, so your answer was pipped-to-the-post by Anantha's. Thank you for your thoughts, though.